# is it good practice to store result in an variable rather than checking it each time in an loop if condition is same all the time

Tags: performance

Say for an example of *printing all the factors of a number*

we know if a number is odd no even numbers can be its factor.
so its code can be written as:

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i+=n%2==0?1:2)
print i;
```

or by using an third variable

```
t=n%2==0?1:2
for(int i=1;i<n;i+=t)
print i;
```

Among both of the above code which one more faster/better ?

Comment: Time it and find out. Note that compiler optimization settings will fix this, and results will vary across languages, and language implementations.

Comment: Good compiler may optimize this, but the second version is more readable and clear. Don't write unclear and strange code only because compiler can handle this.

Answer (score 1):

As rule of thumb, removing computation outside a loop is a good practice. The compiler may not always optimize it (in debug builds it will not try :) ).

One has to be careful not when doing this if the condition can change within the loop. e.g. `n` is not constant during the duration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Executed this peice of code in 3 different ways

```
public class timechk {

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int s=0,n=999999;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if(n%i==0)
                s+=i;
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns"); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Took 4928321 ns
```

Then changed `i++` to `i+=n%2==0?1:2` gave

```
Took 5051085 ns
```

then used third variable:

```
int t=n%2==0?1:2;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i+=t){
```

**Output:**

```
Took 2961729 ns
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace Check the revision history of the question. The tags were added after this answer was posted.

Comment: @Mysticial: My mistake, I should have checked. Thanks!

Comment: The question is, _why_ were those tags added? I can see no evidence that anyone told @egur it was okay to do that. Besides, adding both [tag:c++] _and_ [tag:c] is almost always the wrong thing to do.